# Create a function javascript/jquery that detects clicks on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a function where if I click on a particular image on my site, it'll play a specific audio file that's associated with that picture ONLY. I have some code, but I can't seem to get the function part correct. I want so that everytime you click the image, it'll play the specific audio and when you click it again, it'll pause. I have lots of images on my site. Thank you so much!

Edit: the website wouldn't let my post a screenshot of the code since I'm a new member,

[fiddle. net link][2]

[2]: http:// jsfiddle.net/c8KTg/

Comment: instead of screenshot can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Is that an exam question? Because you have an open exam folder in your screenshot.

Comment: @DangerMonkey, no this is for my own interest. Those are exam materials for a biology class that i'm taking. Here's the jsfiddle.net demo. http://jsfiddle.net/c8KTg/

Comment: To make the question more clearer, lets say I have 100 images on my site that I need to attach a specific audio clip to each. As of right now, I have a .toggle function that sort of works for each image, but I'd rather not make a .toggle event 100 times. So is there a function that I can call upon and pass the imageID and the audioID to and it'll fire .toggle event by itself?

Answer (score 0):

You should revise your audio markup:

```
<audio controls="controls" id="clips">
   <source src="1.mp3" />
   <source src="2.mp3" />    
</audio>
```

Then something like this would probably do it:

```
$('.images').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        var id = this.attr('id');
        var sound_id = id.split('image')[1];
        var music = $('#clips').get(sound_id);
        music.play();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an attribute to get the current track, but you could always declare a global variable or iterate over "source" to find out which to pause.

Comment: you should probably use split() on the '.' and grab the first part as your code will break on the tenth id.